# Javascript : generate variable by for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Am I able to use for loop to declare variables? Because declaring variables with similar one by one is not smart.

For example if I want variables like: DATA1, DATA2 and DATA3, I will normally declare it like below:

```
var data1 = "";

var data2 = "";

var data3 = "";
```

And the below is what I expect we can do in the actual code.

Using for loop and using "i" to assign number for each variable.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3 ;i++){

    var data+i = "";

}
```

am I able to do that? I suppose the above code is not the correct way to do that but just a concept.

Comment: You should never generate variables that way. Especially when there's that sweet data structure called an array.

Comment: so how should i do this with array ? because i cannot predict how many datax i want to have

Comment: `var data=[];` will give you millions of data[x] - read the  [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Arrays don't have a fixed size in JavaScript. You can even build sparse arrays like `var arr=[]; arr[55555]="";`

Comment: This is a frequent question but it's hard to find a correct QA for closing among the thousands of similar ones having so bad answers. Every time it's answered by new coders in a bad way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define Object or Global variable.

```js
var variables = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  variables['data' + i] = i;

}

console.log(variables);

// you can use it like variables.data0


// by the way you can define global variables as you want
// but note that this pollutes the global space

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  window['data' + i] = i;
}
// so you can use it like

console.log(window.data0, ' or ', data0)
```

Comment: can i use for loop to call it?

Comment: like variables.data[i]

Comment: @anson920520. just try it. if it works.. doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Because of the fact that javascript is dynamically typed you can do something like that. JavaScript gives you the possibility of accessing variables through a key.

```
var baseVariable = {};
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    baseVariable["data" + i] = "ValueForData" + i;
}
```

You can than access these variables pretty easy by iterating through the baseVariabel, or if you now the exact amount you can even call it like that:

```
baseVariable.data1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval function to evaluate code from string.
For example:

```
var a = 2; eval('alert(a)');
```

Take a look at assignment chain. May be is would be suitable.

```
var a = b = c = d = e = f = g = "";
```

But this ways is not a good practice.
As mentioned in comments for your question better way to use array or object to store data.